# Update to mysql entry failing, can´t identify the problem, probably related to a timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have two webforms that is used to keep track of confirmations of orders. They interact with the same MySQL database.

This is the database:
[image]

The first webform is used to register an order by the customer service personnel. It only contain the order number used in the internal systems and a time stamp (timelavet).

This is the code for that (and it works):

```
    // Save data
$mySQLQuery = "INSERT INTO bestilling SET godkendelse = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['godkendelse']) . "', ordre = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ordrenummer']) . "', timelavet = NOW() ";
$rs = @mysql_query($mySQLQuery);
```

The second form is used by the customer to confirm the order plus provide some extra information AND a time stamp for the confirmation (timegodkend). It uses the order number to indentify what DB entry to update:

```
// Save data
    $mySQLQuery = "UPDATE bestilling SET kursusleder = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kursusleder']) . "', telefonnummer = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telefonnummer']) . "', email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "', godkendelse = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['godkendelse']) . "', kommentar = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kommentar']) . "', timegodkend = NOW() " . "' WHERE ordre = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ordre']). "'";
    $rs = @mysql_query($mySQLQuery);
```

It doesn´t work! The funny thing is I can get it to work without the timegodkend variable but no matter where I put the  "', timegodkend = NOW() “, it gives me an error message

The error:

> 1064: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '', WHERE ordre = '238581'' at
>   line 1 When executing: UPDATE
>   bestilling SET kursusleder = 'test1',
>   telefonnummer = '2345678', email =
>   'a@brygge.dk', godkendelse = 'Ja',
>   kommentar = 'test', timegodkend =
>   NOW() ', WHERE ordre = ‘238581’

Whats wrong with the second code snippet?

Comment: Remove the comma after NOW()'

Shouldn't it be: 
timegodkend = 'NOW()' WHERE ordre = '238581'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra unmatched quote `'` here:

```
. "', timegodkend = NOW() " . "' WHERE ordre = '" .
                               ^
```

Comment: Ding. Did the job. Next weekend I´ll RTFM :D